# need multi subscriptions to firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have firebase account, and i have my own application (node js) with different users. Each user should have personal info in firestore (its not my side) I connect to firebase with `const db = admin.firestore();` how i can dynamically create subscriptions for all my users so every my application user get only his updates?
so user1 from my app has access to firestore.users.user1 and listen only this events. I don't want listen all events and then filter them, is any separate subscriptions ?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have a database where each user is corresponded to one collection and you would like to restrict access so every user can only access his own collection.

To build user-based and role-based access systems you need [Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)

You may also find helpful this solution for [Secure data access for users and groups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access#rules)